# Click to call with MiTel and SIP

Tags: php, sip

We're looking for a click-to-call system, just with one click let your phone call the number on your screen.

In our company we have lots of MiTel 5320/5330 IP Phones which also have SIP functionality
Since there is a tool called *MiTel Unified Communicator Express* which you can use to start a call, disconnect, redirect and so on. I figured there must be a way for PHP to do this aswell (perhaps with sockets, etc)

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to jump on an old thread, but did you ever find a solution to this? I'm currently trying to implement the exact same solution with a php script. Can't find appropriate api docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click-to-call is implemented using 3rd party call control (3PCC). Look into [RFC3725](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3725) for more technical details. Generally, it's vendor independent and should be supported by Mitel.

There are couple ways to do it:

1. If Mitel provides an API for their UC Express, you can use PHP scripts to delegate click-to-call to Mitel.
2. Use asterisk as a click-to-call server. [This page](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+click+to+call) has more details. In short, whenever a click-to-call link is activated, your webapp sends AMI commends to asterisk to `ORIGINTATE` a call on behave of your user.
3. your webapp implements SIP B2BUA. When a link is clicked, webapp
   initiates INVITE towards caller and callee using one of the 3
   methods recommend in RFC. This is a fair a bit of work especially
   there isn't a ton of stable SIP stack implemented in PHP. You also need more in-depth knowledge on SIP call processing. If you are
   Java, check out [mobicents SIP Servlet stack](http://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/wiki/Welcome?tm=6). They have a nice
   click-to-call demo.

Answer (score 1):

Click-to-call is now part of several standard Mitel add-ons:

https://oneview.mitel.com/s/article/Application-Integration-Solutions